# Parsing JSON array within array with javascript without index

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

Wasn't sure how to phrase the title but here is my problem:

Here is my javascript:

```
$.post("register", element.serialize(),
        function(data){
             if(data.success == "true"){
                           // Do whatever
            } else if (data.success == "false"){

                for (i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++){
                      // This is what I need to change      
                      alert(data.errors[i][0]);
                }
            }
        }, "json");
```

Here is the incoming JSON string:

```
{"success":"false","errors":{"username":"error with username","email":"error with email"}}
```

Broken up, that is:

```
errors: {
   email: "error with email"
   username: "error with username" }
success: "false"
```

I want the alerts to say "error with email" and "error with username"

Nothing I seem to be doing is working though, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: try alert(data.errors.username);

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, i don't necessarily know what the index will be.  I want to display the strings without knowing "email" or "username"

Comment: some of the answers below solve the problem, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.errors` is not an array.  It's an object with properties:

```
data.errors.username
data.errors.email
```

It's unclear from your question what you want to do with those two properties, but that's how you access them.

If you want to iterate the properties of the errors object, you can do that like this:

```
for (var key in data.errors) {
    // data in data.errors[key] here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `errors` property is not an `array` but an `object` with properties.
Here's the code that you should use:

```
alert(data.errors.email);
```

And a valid `array` declaration of objects, note the `[]`:

```
errors: [
   { email: "error with email", username: "error with username" },
   { email: "error with email 2", username: "error with username 2" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for ( in )` loop. This will let you iterate over the object's properties.

```
var msgs = [];
for (var error in errors) {
   msgs.push(errors[error]);
}
```